# Alerts on Build Agents in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Is it possible to get email alerts whenever any build agent in TFS 2018 get offline or stop working?

Comment: If your problem has been solved, can you mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom email subscription:

- Open the Notifications hub under team settings
  `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_admin/_notifications?view=contents`
- Click New subscription (You need to be a team, project, or project collection administrator to create team alerts).
- Select in Category: Build. Template: A build controller or agent's status changes,  click "Next".
- Choose which team members should receive a notification.
- Choose whether you want to receive notifications about activity in all projects or only a specific project.
- Click "Finish".

Comment: This is Good! Thanks!

Comment: Can we do same setting for AzureDevops Server. I checked and couldnt find the option as Select in Category: Build. Template: A build controller or agent's status changes, click "Next".

Answer (score 1):

For TFS itself, there has no such settings or configurations to specify email notification when build agents offline.

But you can achieve it by the event when the agent services are stopped. And you can refer the post [How to send email msg if a windows service stops](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ee23534-01ba-454b-b823-15fb243a51f7/how-to-send-email-msg-if-a-windows-service-stops?forum=winservergen) for detail steps.

Comment: Accepted . Thanks